# AttributeError: module 'pyAudioAnalysis.audioTrainTest' has no attribute 'featureAndTrain'

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am having having the error bellow while running my program. I believe there have been some updates on_ PyAudioAnalysis

AttributeError: module 'pyAudioAnalysis.audioTrainTest' has no attribute 'featureAndTrain'

I am wondering if there is a possibility to update this script:

from pyAudioAnalysis import audioTrainTest as aT
aT.featureAndTrain("...")

Thank you :)

Could not find an answer addressed to this issue online

Comment: Perhaps you want the function `extract_features_and_train()`?  I have no idea if it takes the same parameters as `featureAndTrain()`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. :)  I tried the function you have recommended but it says 'extract_features_and_train' is not defined.

Comment: Try `print(dir(audioTrainTest)) to see what *is* actually defined there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! much appreciated, it finally worked using extract_features_and_train() instead and it took the same parameters :)